When authenticating using solana's provider.signMessage, how secure is the message?
I'm new to this field, so excuse me if it's a basic question with misunderstandings.
I'm thinking of letting a user authenticate an account using solana.
To this end, I can sign a message like this:
const provider = window.phantom.solana;
const encodedMessage = new TextEncoder().encode('my message');
const signedMessage = await provider.signMessage(encodedMessage, "utf8");

Is there an issue with the message being something as simple as "my message"?  Should it be something harder to hack?  Like, "my message 09FAFf33...3l4kF", or does it not matter?
Is there a danger of someone knowing the message and trying to reverse-engineer the user's account keys?
I can already verify the message on a backend server so I don't need help with that. Just wondering about the security of the message itself.

The security of the signature process relies on the cryptographic strength of the private key, not the message.
Before signing, the message is converted to a cryptographic hash which is a unique, fixed-length representation of the message using a secure hashing algorithm (SHA-256 is used in Solana a). The hash is a one-way function, meaning it's computationally infeasible to reverse-engineer the original message from the hash.
Even if someone knows the message, they cannot reverse-engineer your private key from it, because they would need to break the cryptographic algorithms involved, which is nearly impossible with current technology.
But, quantum computing has the potential to threaten current cryptographic algorithms. Current cryptographic systems those used in most modern blockchains, are designed to be secure against traditional computing attacks, but quantum computers can leverage new methods that are more efficient than classical ones.
Recently, Chinese researchers made a breakthrough in quantum computing by using a D-Wave quantum computer to successfully breach military-grade encryption algorithms. From here

Security researchers who have taken a look at the report generally
don't consider the demonstration as posing any current threat to
modern encryption systems, which typically use 2048-bit — or sometimes
even larger — keys. Breaking these 2048-bit keys still remains
computationally unfeasible, and the new research has not changed that
fact.
What it does show, however, is the potential for quantum approaches to
crack modern cryptography in a way that researchers have not
considered before.

